# Is Resolution Intuitionistically Valid?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, intuitionistic-logic

Specifically, is it intuitionistically valid to deduce $Q$ from $P\vee Q$ and $\neg P\vee Q$? The proof I could come up with uses the law of exclusive middle, and I feel that you can probably come up with a clever construction using this resolution principle to deduce LEM, but I haven't been able to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $A \lor B$, if you can prove $C$ from both $A$ and $B$, you can conclude that $C$ is true.

Applying that to our situation, if we can prove $Q$ in all four cases of $P$ and $\neg P$, $P$ and $Q$, $Q$ and $\neg P$, and $Q$ and $Q$, then we can conclude $Q$. The case of $P$ and $\neg P$ can't happen (or alternatively, you can conclude $Q$ from explosion). The remaining cases have $Q$ as a premise, so $Q$ follows.

Comment: Of course, you could technically combine a couple cases using a structure something like: consider the cases of $P\lor Q$.  Case 1: $P$.  In this case, further consider the cases of $\lnot P \lor Q$.  Case 1a: $\lnot P$.  Case 1b: $Q$.  Otherwise, Case 2: $Q$.

Comment: I thought you were wrong at first, but you are right: it is intuitionistically valid to expand $(P \lor Q) \land (\lnot P \lor Q)$ into $(P \land \lnot P) \lor (P \land Q) \lor (Q \land \lnot P) \land (Q \land Q)$. The reason why the resolution procedure for classical logic doesn't work for intuitionistic logic is that the rules for putting formulas into conjunctive normal form are not intuitionistically valid.